# Why memory_order_release support until C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, memory-barriers

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

From cppreference, memory_order_release can use until C++20? Can anyone explain why C++ Standard will delete this and which one memory_order we should use after that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is just a misunderstanding with the formatting of cppreference. It's not that one line that is "until C++20", it's the whole block.

`memory_order_release` isn't removed in C++20. It's just that `memory_order` itself was respecified from being a weak enum:

```
typedef enum memory_order {
    memory_order_relaxed,
    memory_order_consume,
    memory_order_acquire,
    memory_order_release,
    memory_order_acq_rel,
    memory_order_seq_cst
} memory_order;
```

to an enum class (as a result of [P0439](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0439r0.html)):

```
enum class memory_order : /*unspecified*/ {
    relaxed, consume, acquire, release, acq_rel, seq_cst
};
inline constexpr memory_order memory_order_relaxed = memory_order::relaxed;
inline constexpr memory_order memory_order_consume = memory_order::consume;
inline constexpr memory_order memory_order_acquire = memory_order::acquire;
inline constexpr memory_order memory_order_release = memory_order::release;
inline constexpr memory_order memory_order_acq_rel = memory_order::acq_rel;
inline constexpr memory_order memory_order_seq_cst = memory_order::seq_cst;
```

All six memory operations are still there, and are still accessible with the same spelling (although `consume` is discouraged).

Answer (score 4):

You're misreading the table.  It's saying that whole *block* applies to  11 <= C++ < 20.
The block below that defines all the same constants a different way applies to C++ >= 20.

It's just by chance of formatting that the *(until C++20)* is on the same line as `memory_order_release`.  Note that *(since C++11)* is on the same line as `acquire` but clearly applies to all the constants because std::atomic was new in C++11.

**The change is that there's now an `enum class` with short names for the constants:**

```
enum class memory_order : /*unspecified*/ {
    relaxed, consume, acquire, release, acq_rel, seq_cst
};
```

And the full global-scope names are defined in terms of that, e.g. as

```
inline constexpr memory_order memory_order_release = memory_order::release;
```